# How deselect UITableViewCell on long press?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am adding `UILongPressGesture` to `UITableView` and select cell on long press.

I have written some code with that code I'm able to select the cell on the long-press but now I am not able to understand that how to deselect on long-press I show you my code for select on Long Press

In `ViewDidLoad()` I have write below code

```
let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(longPressGesture:)))
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
longPressGesture.delegate = self
self.tblListView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

Here is my LongPress code:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.tblListView)
    let indexPath = self.tblListView.indexPathForRow(at: p)

    if indexPath == nil {
        print("Long press on table view, not row.")
    }
    else if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
        print("Long press on row, at \(indexPath!.row)")
        let cell = self.tblListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! GroupDetailTableViewCell
        cell.btnDeleteMember.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

With this code I am able to select cell but now again on long-press, I want to deselect the cell so I am not able to understand how to do that

Please tell me how to solve this.

So that my problem that how to deselect cell on long-press please tell me how to do that

Thanks

Comment: Is it a multiple selection allowed ?

Comment: No multiple selection not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Global `previousIndexPath` Previous selected Index path

```
    //  Global variable
    var previousIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath()

    @objc func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.tblListView)
        let indexPath = self.tblListView.indexPathForRow(at: p)

        if indexPath == nil {
            print("Long press on table view, not row.")
        }
        else if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
            print("Long press on row, at \(indexPath!.row)")

            // Edited - Add this to reset cell when more than one selected   
            if !previousIndexPath.isEmpty {

               // Reset the Cell
               let cell = self.tblListView.cellForRow(at: previousIndexPath!) as! GroupDetailTableViewCell
               cell.btnDeleteMember.isHidden = true

            }

            let cell = self.tblListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! GroupDetailTableViewCell
            cell.btnDeleteMember.isHidden = previousIndexPath == indexPath ? 
 true : false // This will make the Select and Deselect 
            previousIndexPath = indexPath
          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: if the user clicks 1 cell and selected it , then clicked another 1 it will be selected also

Comment: Thanks! Mate, but with your code only one time select and deselect work

Comment: that's why a reload is needed

Comment: @VishalParmar Now It will work more than one selected ! Just the Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you can want to hide or unhide `btnDeleteMember`. If so use the following code :

```swift
@objc func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.tblListView)
    let indexPath = self.tblListView.indexPathForRow(at: p)
    
    if indexPath == nil {
        print("Long press on table view, not row.")
    }
    else if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
        print("Long press on row, at \(indexPath!.row)")
        let cell = self.tblListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! GroupDetailTableViewCell
         cell.btnDeleteMember.isHidden = !cell.btnDeleteMember.isHidden
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but with unhide i want to remove `indexPath.row` from selected i mean selected indexpath

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
if let selectedIndexPath = self.tblListView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    self.tblListView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
}
```

to deselect cell.